# Managed packaged fields are not visible in report builder

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, report-builder

We are using service max (managed packaged) in our salesforce org and creating report on cases (standard report type). but it is not showing all managed packaged fields in the report builder to system admin.

I have checked the field level security as well, system admin is having edit access on those fields.

I have created one custom report type on case object but still those fields are not available in custom report type as well. only few fields are not available.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does Service Max require you to have a Service Max license in order to view its objects and fields?